# is is Possible oin CYPHER to Set (Copy) the Labels of Another Node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to set the labels of a newly-merged node to the labels of an existing node. I'm pretty sure that the following worked :-

```
SET sub_practice:labels(pract_parent)
```

but it doesn't work in 4.1 and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Doubt it worked before. At the moment, cypher does not support assigning dynamic labels. You will have to use the [APOC library](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/) to achieve this. If you want to create a node with dynamic labels you could use:

```
CALL apoc.create.node(['Label','Label2'], {key:value,property:value})
```

Or you can also just assign dynamic labels to an existing node:

```
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( [node,id,ids,nodes], ['Label','Label2'])
```